# How does product image generation work in Magento?

Tags: image, product-images, small-image

How does product image generation work in Magento?

Comment: Do you mean product image generation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If by image generation you mean product image resize, this is done starting from the class `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image`.
You call the method `init` that receives as parameters an instance of the product model and the code of the image attribute you are trying to resize (`image`, `thumbnail`, `small_image` or any other custom image attribute your have).

This helper class is just a wrapper for the model `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image`
Based on the parameters you set to the `init` method magento retrieves the path to the actual full size image or the placeholder if the image does not exist.

You can set through this helper (that calls the model mentioned above) some attributes of the new image, like width, height, aspect ratio, transparency.

When calling the `__toString` method from the helper (that happens when you call echo $helperInstance) the resized image is generated if it does not exist and the url for it is returned.
The method `__toString` from the helper calls the `saveFile` and `getUrl` methods from the model.

The `saveFile` method from the model calls `getImageProcessor()->save()` method where `getImageProcessor` returns an instance of `Varien_Image`.  that uses an "adapter" to process the image. This adapter is by default and  instance of `Varien_Image_Adapter_Gd2`.
You can start by checking what these classes do and go deeper from there.

The idea is that this adapter makes use of one of the following php functions depending on the image type:

- `magecreatefromgif` - for GIF
- `imagecreatefromjpeg` - for JPEG
- `imagecreatefrompng` - for png
- `imagecreatefromxbm` - for XBM and wbmp

Comment: I have deleted old images, and trying to upload new ones. It throws the following message: Unable to list current working directory.

Comment: check the permissions on the media folder

Comment: I have given 777 to media directory and all subdirectories.

Comment: I am working on 1.9.2 Magento version.

Comment: I have thought that cache could have something to do with this issue, because images are generated fine the first time, on product creation.

Comment: What does the exclude checkbox next to delete ckeckbox on the image upload form? Thanks!

Comment: @Supersonic. It removes the image from the gallery in the product view page.  But for the future, please keep one question per post. If you have multiple questions don't mix them. Create a question for each one of your problems describing them in as many details as possible.